# libunrar.so not found

Tags: archive, libraries, shared-library

I'm having trouble installing `libunrar.so`. 
It's required for [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert CBR files.

Anyone an idea on where to get it (package or source)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download calibre

http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files/

select your system :

64 bits : calibre-x.x.xx-x86_64.tar.bz2

32 bits : calibre-x.x.xx-i686.tar.bz2

extract that file and find libunrar.so in the main directory

copy libunrar.so into "/usr/lib" folder

Comment: Put `libunrar.so` in `/usr/local/lib`, not in `/usr/lib`. Never touch anything under `/usr` outside `/usr/local` without going through the package manager. Also, run `sudo ldconfig` after you've installed a `.so` manually.

Comment: @Gilles, i think is not necesary execute ldconfig in this case because only use (/lib and /usr/lib) man ldconfig and you are using /usr/local/lib

Comment: I have found it named `unrar.so` rather than `libunrar.so` by the way.

Answer (score 8):

[My PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bodiltv/+archive/ppa) contains a libunrar package, if you don't feel like messing around with a manual install.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bodiltv/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

(or just libunrar : `sudo apt-get install libunrar`)

Answer (score 3):

Since Ubuntu 19.10 it is packaged in the repositories as [**libunrar5**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libunrar5&searchon=names):

```
sudo apt install libunrar5
```

It will install the library as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunrar.so.5`, assuming a 64-bit Ubuntu. Since 20.04 there's no 32-bit (i386) version on repositories.

You could also download **UnRAR source** directly from the [official RARLab website](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) and easily build `unrarlib.so` from source:

```sh
wget 'https://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.9.4.tar.gz'
tar -xf 'unrarsrc-5.9.4.tar.gz'
cd unrar
make lib
```

That will produce `unrarlib.so` in the newly created `unrar` directory. Now just move/copy/symlink it to `/usr/local/lib` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

you can grab the libunrar.so file from the latest files here http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files/ , make sure to get the right architecture for your system. 
i got calibre-0.7.23-x86_64.tar.bz2 myself because i have a 64-bit system.

you can then put that libunrar.so file in /usr/lib and hopefully it should work okay

Comment: Put `libunrar.so` in `/usr/local/lib`, not in `/usr/lib`. Never touch anything under `/usr` outside `/usr/local` without going through the package manager. Also, run `sudo ldconfig` after you've installed a `.so` manually.